# How to Store multiple check box selection in SQL Db using ViewBag from View to Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I pass multi-select values from ViewBag to Controller and save in respective data type for Db. With my current Code I am able to take along the values selected in View until the Action method, but post updating Contoller saves only the last values from the selected list for the Property.

It should store info in this format

LeaseID = 1,2,3

LeaseStatus will store as Rented, Vaccant, OwnerOccupied

Currently it saves like = 3 (If selected all 3)

Below is my Action Method

```
public ActionResult ReviewProperty(Property model, List<Leasing> LeasingStatus)
{
int id = model.PropId;

            

var uName = User.Identity.Name;


if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
return View(model);
}

using (Db db = new Db())
{
Property dto = db.Properties.Find(id);

dto.OwnerName = model.OwnerName;
dto.OwnerMobNumber = model.OwnerMobNumber;
dto.AlterContactNum = model.AlterContactNum;
dto.OwnerEmail = model.OwnerEmail;
dto.PropertyStatus = model.PropertyStatus;

db.SaveChanges();

foreach(var lease in LeasingStatus)
{
dto.LeaseID = lease.LeaseID;
                    
}
Leasing leaseDTO = db.Leasings.Where(x => x.LeaseID == dto.LeaseID).ToArray().ToList().FirstOrDefault();

dto.LeaseStatus = leaseDTO.LeaseStatus;

db.Properties.Add(dto);

db.SaveChanges();
}

TempData["SM"] = "Changes successfully updated!";

return RedirectToAction("MyPendingTask");
}
```

View

```
@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.ListLease.Count; i++)
{
<div class="form-row">


<div class="form-check">

<input type="checkbox" id="@ViewBag.ListLease[i].LeaseStatus" name="[@i].LeaseID" value="@ViewBag.ListLease[i].LeaseID" checked="@ViewBag.ListLease[i].isChecked" />
<label class="form-check-label">
@ViewBag.ListLease[i].LeaseStatus
</label>
</div>

</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the data outside the loop so that you save the data inside the loop, this will save all your data, all ids

```cs
foreach (var lease in LeasingStatus)
{
    dto.LeaseID = lease.LeaseID;
    Leasing leaseDTO = db.Leasings.Where(x => x.LeaseID == dto.LeaseID).ToArray().ToList().FirstOrDefault();

    dto.LeaseStatus = leaseDTO.LeaseStatus;
    db.Properties.Add(dto);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ramesh I did try your solution so, it duplicate entries in Db with selected LeaseID, then I simply tried to SaveChanges() and remove Add(dto), and there is no success. Again it save the last selected CheckBox and not the 2 I selected.

Comment: try to use `IEnumerable<int> yourID` i hope this helpful for you @RS